# Node.js express POST request not getting parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post, express

I have the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/rasp', function(req, res) {
res.send("received");
res.send(req.body.data);
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

I used POSTMAN to see if it worked and apparently the "received" text is sent back, but the data parameter is blank. What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you still have this issue if you remove `res.send("received");`? and if you add `console.log(req.body);` what is the result?

Comment: "I used POSTMAN to see if it worked" — How? Exactly what request did you send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the client sends a request and waits for a single response from your server. Once the client receives that response, it stops waiting for another. Furthermore, Express only allows you to send one response per request (going along with the client stuff explained above). You may be able to change this setting, but I've never dealt with it, so my answer will be limited to that knowledge.

Your server is executing `res.send('received');` and the response is handled. You cannot call `res.send` again. You should be getting an error on your server when you attempt the second call.

You should send all data that the client needs in the first (and only) `res.send()`.

Server responses should not be handled like logging (ex: sending 'received', 'analyzing', etc). Keep the logging separate. The client doesn't want to know all that extra info, it just wants the expected data response.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, now it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);

app.post('/rasp', function(req, res) {

    res.send({received:true,data:req.body});

});
```

can you try this one and writing the response here

Answer (score 0):

I believe your post body is "data=Some Value".

If you want to send multiple chunks of data, you should use res.write, and res.end. In your code change the following lines

```
res.send("received");
res.send(req.body.data);
```

to

```
res.write("received");
res.end(req.body.data);
```